# Convert List<double[]> to double[,]

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Say I have a

```
List<double[]> x = new List<double[]>();
double[] item = new double[] {1.0,2.0,3.0};
x.add(item);
etc...
```

Is there a faster/cleaner way to get this into a double[,] then looping it:

```
double[,] arr = new double[x.Count,3];          
for (row = 0; row < x.Count; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        arr[row,col] = x[row][col];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Multi-dimensional arrays are strange beasts and are not widely accepted or used in the BCL.

They're also slow and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: I hadn't heard of performance issues either.  Maybe you are thinking of jagged arrays instead of multi-dimensional ones?  Also, VB is happy to work with multi-dimensional arrays.  VB is the lowest common denominator as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: IIRC, multi-dimensional array access is done through system calls, causing the slowness, unlike single-dimensional array access which is done directly with CIL instructions.

Comment: @Scott: On the contrary.  Jagged arrays are fully normal; multi-dimensional ones are slow.  Qwertie is correct.  I'm talking about BCL methods, not language support.  Also, VB is not the lowest common denominator - exception filters, interface maps, etc

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the explanation. Have you any idea how much of a difference we are talking about?  I analyze a lot of 3D data and routinely use multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Scott: No idea.  If you're concerned, run a profiler or do a simple test.

Answer (score 2):

Because I felt like it, I solved this using LINQ, however, it's hardly any cleaner. In fact, I'd argue it's less clear, but it'd danm neat :)

```
// Input
List<double[]> a = new List<double[]>() { 
    new double[]{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 },
    new double[]{ 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 },
    new double[]{ 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 }
};

// Output
var b = a.Select((item, index) => new 
            { 
                Items = item.Select((inner, inIndex) => new { Inner = inner, Y = inIndex }),
                X = index 
            })
            .SelectMany(item => item.Items, (i, inner) => new { Value = inner.Inner, X = i.X, Y = inner.Y })
            .Aggregate(new double[a.Count, a.Max(aa => aa.Length)], (acc, item) => { acc[item.X, item.Y] = item.Value; return acc; })
```

*Note: This also works for arbitrarily sized inner `double[]` arrays, but there will be empty spots.*

So yes, there's **another** way of doing it, but it's not a **better** way :)

Comment: +1 for taking the time to investigate. Going through the process only to decide this approach is not so practical is still a useful bit of knowledge IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the `var_export` function?

Comment: Wow.. Good response. That is very, both productive and helpful!